# npm install -g react-native-cli

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

Hello i'm trying to instal react native but on running `npm install -g react-native-cli` it brings the following error on Command Prompt.

```
npm ERR! code EINVAL
npm ERR! path C:\WINDOWS\system32\'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! Illegal characters in path.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-06T17_33_30_954Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to clean cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then run

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

**Or**

delete your nodemodules folder

and then run

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error:

```
npm ERR! EINVAL: invalid argument, utime
```

And was solved the issue with message:

By doing the following steps:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
cd your_project_directory
rmdir /s /q node_modules
npm install
```

That, basically upgrade the node package, then refresh the project's packages. Hope this brings down your error!